# Toast on SMS receive ANDROID STUDIO NOT WORKING

Tags: android, sms

For the program of toast presentation on sms receive in ANDROID STUDIO,Im getting no errors...but it is not working in any of my phones(Used Samsung GT-i9082 and lenovo a6000+)..Here is my code and the manifest following respectively.. ...

```
package com.myapplication.siva.phoneapp;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity{
private BroadcastReceiver receiver;
public static final String SMS_BUNDLE = "pdus";
private static String TAG="com.myapplication.siva.phoneapp";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Log.i(TAG,"Inside onCreate");
    receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Bundle intentExtras = intent.getExtras();
            Log.i(TAG,"Inside on Receive");
            try {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Coming Inside",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.i(TAG,"Inside try");
                if (intentExtras != null) {
                    Object[] sms = (Object[]) intentExtras.get(SMS_BUNDLE);
                    String smsMessageStr = "";
                    for (int i = 0; i < sms.length; ++i) {
                        SmsMessage smsMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) sms[i]);

                        String smsBody = smsMessage.getMessageBody().toString();
                        String address = smsMessage.getOriginatingAddress();

                        smsMessageStr += "SMS From: " + address + "\n";
                        smsMessageStr += smsBody + "\n";
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(context, smsMessageStr, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.i(TAG,"Some Exception");
            }
        }
    };
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.myapplication.siva.phoneapp" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.hardware_test"></uses-permission>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
   <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
       <receiver
           android:name=".MainActivity"
           android:enabled="true"
           android:exported="true">
       <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"> </action>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
       </receiver>
    </activity>

</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Well, one problem is that your `<receiver>`'s `<intent-filter>` should have `"android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"` as the `<action>`, not `"com.myapplication.siva.myapplication"`. Also, since Android 3.1, you need to include an Activity that the user can run at least once to bring the app out of its _stopped_ state. Your BroadcastReceiver won't work until then.

Comment: I updated the given corrections..Even though its not working..The Program above is the one which i updated...

Answer (score 0):

Mike M is perfectly correct your intent filter should contain action for sms, i.e., `"android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"` not something else.

Secondly you require an activity to launch am broadcast receiver from android 3.1 for security issues.